# Generate XML having repeated parent tags from JSON

Tags: java, json, xml, spring

I am using XmlMapper in Java to create XML from JSON

The required XML structure is:

```
<Months>
 <Month>May</Month>
 <Month>August</Month>
 <Month>November</Month>
 <Month>February</Month>
</Months>
```

How should my JSON look like to have the above format of XML?

I tried my JSON as below, but that did not return a valid output

```
"Months": ["May",
           "August",
           "November",
           "February"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  "Months": [
    {"Month": "May"},
    {"Month": "August"},
    {"Month": "November"},
    {"Month": "February"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
"Months" : ["May", "August", "November", "February"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly

```json
"Months": [ 
   { "Month": "May" }, 
   { "Month": "August" }, 
   { "Month": "November" }, 
   { "Month": "February" },
]
```